# How to change connection type of SSRS report Data source dynamically

Tags: c#, reporting-services, reportviewer

I have an application that binds the RDL file on report server to Report viewer control to produce reports. We use embedded data source in the RDL file. We have used expression based connection string for our embedded data source So that we will be able to change the data source dynamically.

We wanted to access the report using both windows integrated security and SQL server authentication. Now if our data source is configured to use windows integrated security and we wanted to access the report using SQL authentication, then we are modifying the RDL file using web methods before producing the report.

Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to used a shared data source , that all your RDL files map to . this way the changes are limited to one data source

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
We cannot use a data source that is a shared one.
We found the below the link that solves the problem

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/607382/Running-a-RDL-RDLC-SQL-Report-in-ASP-NET-without-S